# Minimal polynomial of $\alpha \in \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{d})$

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, minimal-polynomials

Given some cubefree $d$, is there a general way to determine the minimal polynomial over $\mathbb{Q}$ of $\alpha=1+\sqrt[3]{d}+\sqrt[3]{d^2} \in \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{d})$? Or more generally, $\alpha=a+b\sqrt[3]{d}+c\sqrt[3]{d^2}, a,b,c \in \mathbb{Q}$?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's the minimal polynomial of the $\mathbb Q$-linear transformation $x \mapsto \alpha x$. Use the basis $\{1,\sqrt[3]{d},\sqrt[3]{d^2}\}$.

Comment: Thanks! I'm wondering how to do this the long way by definitions though. If I wanted to find the minimal polynomial for $3+\sqrt{2}$ over $\mathbb{Q}$, I could set $x= 3+\sqrt{2}$ and see that $(x-3)^2=2$, which gives us the minimum polynomial. Is there a way to do this for cube roots by making use of conjugates? My issue is that I don't know how to write down the conjugate of a cube root like I can for a square root (e.g. $a+b\sqrt2$ and $a-b\sqrt 2$).

Comment: @A.B, you may be able to get some success in special cases by algebraic manipulation, but one systematic way is by using matrices as above. There are several examples of this technique in this site.

Comment: The naive way mentioned by the OP somewhat generalizes by searching the minimal $n$ giving a linear relations between $\alpha^0,\ldots,\alpha^n$, though it is exactly the same as searching the minimal polynomial of the matrix of the multiplication by $\alpha$

Answer (score 0):

Yes, You have that
\begin{equation}
\mathbb{Q}\subset\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{d})
\end{equation}
$\alpha$ is algebraic, since that
\begin{equation}
\alpha=\sqrt[3]{d}\Rightarrow \alpha^3-d=0
\end{equation}
Then the minimal polynomial are $p(x)=x^3-d$, the $[\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{d}):\mathbb{Q}]=3$, the  a basis $\mathbb{Q}$ over $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{d})$ is:

\begin{equation}
\lbrace 1,\sqrt[3]{d},(\sqrt[3]{d})^2\rbrace
\end{equation}
so
\begin{equation}
\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{d})=\lbrace a+b\sqrt[3]{d}+c(\sqrt[3]{d})^2\big{|}a,b,c\in\mathbb{Q}\rbrace
\end{equation}